# Relative paths in Joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla

I´m getting this error:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required  
'JPATH_ROOT/plugins/system/bfstop/Sdkphp/vendor/autoload.php'
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in    
/var/www/public/plugins/system/bfstop/helpers/dynamodb.php on line 16
```

I´m trying to set a relative path, but I don´t understand how joomla works.

The real relative paths is this:

```
require '../Sdkphp/vendor/autoload.php';
```

I was searching about paths in Joomla 3, I found this:

https://docs.joomla.org/Constants

But it doesn´t work. I don´t understand this because I have made a lot of webs and a lot of programs using paths why it doesn´t work?

My folder structure:

- Joomla

  - plugins

    - system

      - myplugin

        - helpers

          - dynamodb.php
        - Sdkphp

          - Vendor

            - autoload.php

And path is from dynamodb.php to autoload.php, as I say:

"../Sdkphp/Vendor/autoload.php"

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
require (JPATH_PLUGINS . '/myplugin/Skdphp/Vendor/autoload.php');
```